# Google OR Tools Constraint SetCoefficient, setting linear inequalities

Tags: python, linear-programming, or-tools

From Google's OR-Tools Linear Solver [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/stigler_diet) this block of code is referenced.

```py
foods = [solver.NumVar(0.0, solver.infinity(), item[0]) for item in data]

# Create the constraints, one per nutrient.
constraints = []
for i, nutrient in enumerate(nutrients):
    constraints.append(solver.Constraint(nutrient[1], solver.infinity()))
    for j, item in enumerate(data):
        constraints[i].SetCoefficient(foods[j], item[i + 3])

print('Number of constraints =', solver.NumConstraints())
```

`Solver.Constraint` appears to accept a lower bound and upper bound arguments. However, when this constraint is later referenced in the nested for loop and the method, `.SetCoefficient` is referenced, `foods[j]` retrieves from list, `foods`, a `NumVar` object and `item[i+3]` retrieves the nutrient i of food item j. But beyond here, I can't make sense of what SetCoefficient is doing and how this functions as a linear constraint.

The [source code](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/linear_solver/pywraplp) provides the following guidance:

```py
class Constraint(object):
    r"""
    The class for constraints of a Mathematical Programming (MP) model.

    A constraint is represented as a linear equation or inequality.
    """

    thisown = property(lambda x: x.this.own(), lambda x, v: x.this.own(v), doc="The membership flag")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise AttributeError("No constructor defined")
    __repr__ = _swig_repr
...
    def SetCoefficient(self, var: "Variable", coeff: "double") -> "void":
        r"""
        Sets the coefficient of the variable on the constraint.

        If the variable does not belong to the solver, the function just returns,
        or crashes in non-opt mode.
        """
        return _pywraplp.Constraint_SetCoefficient(self, var, coeff)
```

> Define the constraints
> The constraints for Stigler diet require the total amount of the nutrients provided by all foods to be at least the minimum requirement for each nutrient. Next, we write these constraints as inequalities involving the arrays data and nutrients, and the variables food[i].

> First, the amount of nutrient i provided by food j per dollar is data[j][i+3] (we add 3 to the column index because the nutrient data begins in the fourth column of data.) Since the amount of money to be spent on food j is food[j], the amount of nutrient i provided by food j is ( data[j][i+3] \cdot food[j] ). Finally, since the minimum requirement for nutrient i is nutrients[i](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/stigler_diet), we can write constraint i as follows: [ \sum_{j} data[j][i+3] \cdot food[j] \geq nutrients[i](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/stigler_diet) ;;;;; (1) ] The following code defines these constraints.

I don't understand the syntax of these constraints. A typical linear constraint might take the form of `x + 2*y <= 3`; however, the syntax here doesn't function that way. How should I use OR-Tools library to define constraints in this more conventional way?

Likewise, what is the usage of SetCoefficient doing and how does it establish a constraint in the form of an inequality?

Comment: 1) `SetCoefficient` is just a sparse coordinate-format. See [scipy.sparse](https://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/scipy_sparse/coo_matrix.html) (for the more common 2d-equivalent). Each coefficient is a non-zero weight of some variable (as vars are usually the columns of the constraint-matrix). 2) Most low-level solver-APIs use range-constraints. An inequality `<=` has an infinite lower bound. And `>=` has an infinite upper bound. Usually one needs to check if the API asks for special *sentinels*. e.g. `solver.infinity()` in your code. 3) `x + 2*y <= 3 <-> -infinity <= 1 * x + 2 * y <= 3`.

Comment: Why don't you use the API with operators: https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/lp_example ?

Comment: So, I'm still a little unsure what the diet problem code block referenced in the question is doing. I believe it does 5 things: 1/ Create an array, foods, of NumVar objects, 2/ create an empty array for constraints, 3/ initialize constraints with lower & upper bounds, 4/ assign it the specific NumVar object and the specific nutrient-food value, & 5/ append it to the constraints array. I had believed that constraints had to take the form of inequalities; this seems to be assigning an equality eg `{cake|sugar} = 10`. Pardon my ignorance but is assigning equalities allowed or do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

One of my great frustrations when I try to program math is that the code I write never comes out as elegantly as the math I started with, and the same is true here, I think. I have a pretty good background in math and programming, but I also found this example to be quite opaque at first.

For the function `setCoefficient()`, the term "coefficient" in this context means a [matrix coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_coefficient) of the constraint matrix. ([This PDF](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/H-lp.pdf) is a good presentation of the math behind linear programming. The definitions are on page 2.)

What the program is doing is defining a constraint matrix where the rows are the `i` nutrients, the columns are the `j` foods, and the coefficients define the amount of nutrient `i` given by food `j`. In the code, `SetCoefficient(foods[j], item[i + 3])` defines the constraint matrix coefficient by coefficient.

So, the `nutrients x foods` constraint matrix multiplies with the `foods x 1` variable vector to make a `nutrients x 1` vector. In this resulting vector,  nutrient `i` from food `j` (the coefficient above) will only be used in the final summation for nutrient `i`, so we only need to add its value to `constraint[i]`. That is: `constraints[i].SetCoefficient(foods[j], item[i + 3])`